# Getting Last Login Time Of Facebook User

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my Facebook app, I want to know users login history. Is there any way by which I can get information about when the user was last logged in on Facebook (on Facebook, not on my app) ?

I studied the Facebook Graph API and tried to get user information using `$Facebook->api('/me');`, and referring to `user` object of Graph API, but nowhere could I find information related to user's login history.

Does Facebook not provide user's login history details ? Or do I need to follow a different approach ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No, there is no such info available via API.

Comment: Also looking forward to see anwser

Comment: If they would you could easily estimate the Monthly Active User Count. Therefore Social Networks usually do not publish these information.